# Connect each tab in shinydashboardPlus sidebar with a different tab in the main body after clicking on it

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Is there a way to connect every tab of the right sidebar in a `shinydashboardPlus` with a different tab in the main body? Every time the user clicks on the icon of the right sidebar tab he wants he would move to the respective tab in the body.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
shinyApp(
    ui = tags$body(class="skin-blue sidebar-mini control-sidebar-open",dashboardPagePlus(
        header = dashboardHeaderPlus(
            enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
            rightSidebarIcon = "gears"
        ),
        sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
        body = dashboardBody(),
        rightsidebar = rightSidebar(
            background = "dark",
            rightSidebarTabContent(
                id = 1,
                title = "Tab 1",
                icon = "desktop",
                active = TRUE,
                sliderInput(
                    "obs",
                    "Number of observations:",
                    min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500
                )
            ),
            rightSidebarTabContent(
                id = 2,
                title = "Tab 2",
                textInput("caption", "Caption", "Data Summary")
            ),
            rightSidebarTabContent(
                id = 3,
                icon = "paint-brush",
                title = "Tab 3",
                numericInput("obs", "Observations:", 10, min = 1, max = 100)
            )
        ),
        title = "Right Sidebar"
    )),
    server = function(input, output) { }
)
```

Comment: It is easier to show different rightsidebar for each tab in the body.  Otherwise you are limited to 5 tabs on the rightsidebar.